# parameter estimation on the LDA model

Tags: estimation, bayesian-network, gibbs, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have a problem with estimating the parameters of $\theta$, and $\phi$ in the Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) model. The article [Finding scientific topics](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/101/suppl_1/5228.full.pdf) has done the estimation of the parameters using the Gibbs sampling algorithm. I have no problem in Gaining the conditional distribution, but I don't know how mathematically the relations for estimating the mentioned parameters are obtained. 
The relations for estimating parameters as follow: 
$$
    \Phi^{(w)}_j = \frac{n^{(w)}_j + \beta}{n^{(.)}_j+W\beta}
    \label{eq.6}
$$

$$
    \Theta^{(d)}_j = \frac{n^{(d)}_j + \alpha}{n^{(d)}_.+T\alpha}
    \label{eq.7}
$$